# Updating date in controller not reflected in input type=date

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In AngularJS, I have on the DOM side:

```
<input class="form-control"  type="date" ng-model="scope.status.date"
       ng-change="scope.reloadDay()" ng-model-options="{debounce:200}">
```

In the back I have a function:

```
scope.changeDate = function() {
    var current_date   = scope.status.date;
    current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate() - 1);
    scope.status['date'] = current_date;
}
```

This results that indeed `scope.status.date` is updated, but in the input box it stays the same.

What is happening here?

Comment: Please show the exact value of scope.status.date

Comment: after modify you need pars in date object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a new Date:

```
$scope.changeDate = function() {
    var current_date = $scope.status.date;
    current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate() - 1);
    $scope.status.date = new Date(current_date);
};
```

This will trigger the `$render()` function of the `ngModelController`.

### The DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.status = {date: new Date()};

    $scope.changeDate = function() {
        var current_date = $scope.status.date;
        current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate() - 1);
        $scope.status.date = new Date(current_date);
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
     <input class="form-control"  type="date" ng-model="status.date"
            ng-model-options="{debounce:200}">
     <br>
     <button ng-click="changeDate()">Change Date</button>

</body>
```

---

> Would have never thought of this that this triggers the render(). May I ask how you found this in the documentations? What did you look for?

From the Docs:

> ### `$render();`
>
> Since `ng-model` does not do a deep watch, `$render()` is only invoked if the values of `$modelValue` and `$viewValue` are actually different from their previous values. If `$modelValue` or `$viewValue` are objects (rather than a string or number) then **`$render()` will not be invoked if you only change a property on the objects.**
>
> — [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference - $render](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#ngModel.NgModelController-methods)

For more information, see

- [How does data binding work in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9693933/5535245)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope `$watch` Depths](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-watch-depths)

Comment: Interesting! Would have never thought of this that this triggers the render(). May I ask how you found this in the documentations? What did you look for?

Answer (score -1):

Please check a date format, date format should be "yyyy-mm-dd"

Comment: `ng-model` binds the value to inputs, `value` attribute not needed

Comment: yes you are right now I have updated my answer and can you check your date format because HTML 5 accept yyyy-mm-dd format.@Bill p